# Restart a VideoGame in Python

Tags: python, pygame

i had some problem trying to create a pop up message for my minigame in python, when i try the option no and exit from the game is all good, but, when i try the option yes, the game continues displaying the game and the pop up. Thanks for all the answers.
Code:

```
  Tk().wm_withdraw() #nascondo la finestra del gioco
  if messagebox.askyesno('Hai perso!','Vuoi riprovare?') == False:
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
  elif messagebox.askyesno('Hai perso!','Vuoi riprovare?') == True:
    game_over = False
    main()
```

Comment: You're calling `messagebox.askyesno()` twice if the first if statement condition is not met. You probably want to use `if / else` instead of asking the user twice.

Comment: Keep in mind that `if messagebox.askyesno('Hai perso!','Vuoi riprovare?') == False:` doesn't just check what option was picked, it *causes the options to appear*. If you do that twice, they will appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be the following to work properly:

```py
if messagebox.askyesno('Hai perso!','Vuoi riprovare?') == False:
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
else:
    game_over = False
    main()
```

Tell me if it works!

Comment: unluckly it doesn't work, and i cant post all the code:(